# How to play video in android app without increasing apk size

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I want to play a video in an android app, offline.

But putting the video file in the asset or raw or drawable folder increases my apk size.

Is there any other way to play a video offline?

Comment: No, to play a video offline you need to have a copy of the video stored on the device somewhere. I suppose you could download it after the user installs the app, but that's not very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the video from a server sometime when your app is online.

Or, if you are distributing through the Play Store, use [an APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). This does not change how much space you take up, but it may help if your video is too large for a Play Store APK.

Comment: But when will i share app through any file transfer i ll also need to share tht obb file or need to download tht obb file again.. So it will be tidious job to use app..